# ComboBox DropDownList with Text support

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've created a ComboBox which supports drawing text on the control when the DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList.

The below snippet does not match the rest of the codes structure, and also does not use proper checking from e.States. Does anyone know which e.States I should check for this?

```
if (!this.DroppedDown && e.Index == -1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_dropDownListText, e.Font, b, e.Bounds);
        }
        else if (e.Index > -1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ItemName(e.Index), e.Font, b, e.Bounds);
        }
```

And the full code, with the above snippet commented out for ease of search

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    private ToolTip _toolTip = new ToolTip();
    private string _dropDownListText = "Select...";

    public ComboBoxEx()
    {
        this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    }

    [Description("Gets or sets the text associated with DropDownList style."), Category("Appearance")]
    public string DropDownListText
    {
        get
        {
            return _dropDownListText;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }
            _dropDownListText = value;
        }
    }

    public string ItemName(int index)
    {
        if (index == -1)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        // return the selected item value from the ComboBoxEx.Item class
        return ((ComboBoxEx.Item)(this.Items[index])).Name;
    }

    public string ItemTag(int index)
    {
        if (index == -1)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        // return the selected item tag from the ComboBoxEx.Item class
        return ((ComboBoxEx.Item)(this.Items[index])).Tag;
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // force a redraw of DropDownListText if necessary
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
        base.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {

        // select the brush to use as the fore color
        SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush((this.Enabled ? SystemColors.WindowText : SystemColors.GrayText));

        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Focus) == DrawItemState.Focus)
        {
            // fill the focused items rectangle
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Info), e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            // fill the rest of the rectangle
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Window), e.Bounds);
        }

// for ease of reading, I've commented the code out. This code should use proper if then e.State checks so that I can combine it with the rest of the Else If Then statements
        /* 
        if (!this.DroppedDown && e.Index == -1)
        {
            // redraw the dropdownlist text when the combobox is closed with no index selected
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_dropDownListText, e.Font, b, e.Bounds);
        }
        else if (e.Index > -1)
        {
            // else, draw the selected item value
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ItemName(e.Index), e.Font, b, e.Bounds);
        }
*/
        if (e.State == (DrawItemState.Disabled | DrawItemState.NoAccelerator | DrawItemState.NoFocusRect | DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit))
        {
            // redraw the dropdownlist text when the control is disabled
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_dropDownListText, e.Font, b, 3, 3);
        }
        else if (e.State == (DrawItemState.NoAccelerator | DrawItemState.NoFocusRect | DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) && e.Index == -1)
        {
            // redraw the dropdownlist text when the control is dropped down with no index selected
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_dropDownListText, e.Font, b, 3, 3);
        }
        else if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            if (e.Index > -1 && this.DroppedDown)
            {
                // show a tool tip on the right side of the control with the selected item tag
                _toolTip.Show(ItemTag(e.Index), this, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom + 5);
            }
            else
            {
                // hide the tool tip when the control is no longer dropped down
                _toolTip.Hide(this);
            }
        }

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        b.Dispose();

    }

    public class Item : object
    {
        protected string _name;
        protected string _tag;

        public Item(string name, string tag)
        {
            _name = name;
            _tag = tag;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
        }

        public string Tag
        {
            get
            {
                return _tag;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
    ComboBoxEx1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxEx.Item("Marks Number", "1-555-555-1000"));
    ComboBoxEx1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxEx.Item("Jacks Number", "1-555-555-1001"));
    ComboBoxEx1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxEx.Item("Daves Number", "1-555-555-1002"));
    ComboBoxEx1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxEx.Item("Joses Number", "1-555-555-1003"));
```

Feel free to use this code for your own use.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but in order to do this we ask that you first create a question that this information can answer, then answer it accordingly. If you can do this, I'm happy to re-open the question.